# OpenGl ES version3 and google maps

Tags: android

In my application I'm using google maps so I've added in my manifest:

```
    <uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>
```

Now a friend of mine cannot install it (using Note 3) is this because Note3 supports openGL 3 ? if so how can I set my manifest so It can be installed correctly?

Comment: That entry in the manifest specifies that the device needs to support **at least** ES 2.0. It won't prevent it from installing on devices that support higher versions, like 3.0. There must be a different reason why it refuses to install.

Comment: yeah you are right, could you write that comment as an answer so that O can close this question?

Comment: Sure, yes. Did you figure out why it's not installing?

Comment: no not yet but ES is irrelevant, as you said 2 means at least 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `glEsVersion` entry in `AndroidManifest.xml` specifies the **minimum** OpenGL ES version required. The value you are using (`0x00020000`) corresponds to ES 2.0. This will allow installation on any device with ES 2.0 or higher.

So this manifest entry will not prevent your app from being installed on devices with ES 3.0 support. I suspect that there is something else going on. Could be something else in your manifest. Or if you are side loading the app, make sure that your friend has the settings enabled that allow installation of non-market apps.